# Is ناس related etymologically or in any other ways to نسیان?

Tags: arabic

It is claimed [here](https://youtu.be/5CCgT4viZuA), at 14:03, that one possible root of ناس is نسیان.

Is it true?
Can it be supported linguistically?

Comment: I've heard that too and always wanted to investigate more... Thanks for giving me a reason... However I'm too busy these days let's see. .

Comment: Basically among the statements of linguists this is one of two roots that have been attributed to انسان. I'll try to write that down in an answer later.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, thank you for that. I wish we had access to the true knowledge of the Quran. Just imagine hearing the true meaning of most of the verses from the Prophet himself (PBUH). What a blessing Sahaba had. May Allah give us more piety.